# How to use println! on an int

Tags: ats

In the code below, the line `val () =  println! ("-> ", nn)` generates an error:

```
$ myatscc collatz.dats
/home/brandon/workspace/ATStest/collatz/collatz.dats: 203(line=13, offs=13) -- 225(line=13, offs=35): error(3): the symbo
l [print] cannot be resolved due to too many matches:
D2ITMcst(print_option) of 0
D2ITMcst(print_list_vt) of 0
/home/brandon/workspace/ATStest/collatz/collatz.dats: 203(line=13, offs=13) -- 225(line=13, offs=35): error(3): the dynam
ic expression cannot be assigned the type [S2Ecst(atsvoid_t0ype)].
/home/brandon/workspace/ATStest/collatz/collatz.dats: 203(line=13, offs=13) -- 225(line=13, offs=35): error(3): mismatch
of static terms (tyleq):
The actual term is: S2Eerrexp()
The needed term is: S2Ecst(atsvoid_t0ype)
patsopt(TRANS3): there are [2] errors in total.
exit(ATS): uncaught exception: _2home_2brandon_2workspace_2ATS_2dPostiats_2src_2pats_error_2esats__FatalErrorExn(1025)
```

Here is the code

```
(*
 To compile:
 myatscc collatz.dats
*)

#include "share/atspre_staload.hats"

//TODO: add guards to make sure nn is non-negative
fun collatz(nn: int): int = let
  val newN: int =
    if nn % 2 = 0 then nn / 2
    else 3 * nn + 1 
  //FIXME: too many matches: print_option or print_list_vt:
  // val () =  println! ("-> ", nn)  
  //FIXME: Why is this not printing:
  val () =  println! ("-> ", 1)  
in 
  if (newN: int) != (1: int) then collatz(newN)
  else newN
end

implement
main0 () = {
 val _ = collatz(42)
}
```

I'm also confused as to why the dummy println! isn't executed (`val () =  println! ("-> ", 1)`).

Here's a program in Scala ([run it online](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/9Xs6tIU/7)) that does what I'm going for:

```
@tailrec
def collatz(n: BigInt): BigInt = {
 assert (n > 0)
 val newN = 
  if (n % 2 == 0) n / 2
  else 3 * n + 1
 println(s"-> $newN") 
 if (newN != 1) collatz(newN)
 else newN
}

collatz(BigInt("7893450809435834508"))
```

Comment: Your code works when I tried it.

Comment: You probably used an old version of ATS. Try to use ATS2-0.3.9.

Comment: yes, I was using 0.3.7; I guess it is older than I thought! Will try it soon

Comment: bumping versions worked! also I didn't seem to have the need to do `val newN = (if nn % 2 = 0 then nn / 2 else 3 * nn + 1): int` as mentioned on the forum. Here is a working program: https://github.com/bbarker/ATStest/blob/master/collatz/collatz.dats

Comment: This is due to `(newN: int)` being present in the later part of the code.

Comment: The project isn't fully complete, but my atspkg will get the latestt compiler and make pinning compilers easy http://github.com/vmchale/atspkg